# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in FormulairesController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested

I followed this tutorial for nested forms (http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?autoplay=true). I have to create Forms / Questions / Answers. It's ok for forms and questions but when i want to Insert answers in my DB it doesn't work.

I tried two methods create :

```
def create
  @formulaire = current_user.formulaires.new(formulaire_params)
  if @formulaire.save    
    redirect_to @formulaire, notice: "Votre formulaire a bien été crée"   
  else     
    render :new
   end
 end
```

and
     #@formulaire = Formulaire.new(params[:formulaire])

My formulaire_params method :

```
    def formulaire_params
      params.require(:formulaire).permit(:name, :description,       questions_attributes: [:id,:nom, :typequestion,
      answer_attributes:[:id, :content]]) if params[:formulaire]
end
```

In my view I have a form with fields_for :answers with a text_field content but nothing is insert in my DB.

Thankyou

Comment: Can you share the top of your Models (associations and the `accepts_nested_attributes` part) as well what shows up in the logs as params being passed through one you submit your form?

Comment: @inveterateliterate I shared it. Ty

Comment: Thanks. You should add that code to your question (or leave a comment if you are unable to edit your question). Also, the logs you posted appear to be the action for the show page, I don't see the` POST /formulaires/` with the form params. It would also help to include your form.

Comment: I submitted as a comment @inveterateliterate .

Answer (score 0):

```
 class Formulaire < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user
has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, :reject_if => lambda { |a|       a[:nom].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true


 validates :name, presence: true
 validates :description, presence: true

end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :formulaire
has_many :answers, :dependent => :destroy
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :allow_destroy => true

 #self.inheritance_column = nil
enum typequestion: [:reponse_courte, :choix_multiple, :choix_simple]

end
```

And the logs when I create a submit a form :

```
Started GET "/formulaires/112" for 88.172.93.170 at 2017-12-17 19:49:26     +0000
 Cannot render console from 88.172.93.170! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
 Processing by FormulairesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"112"}
  Formulaire Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "formulaires".* FROM "formulaires" WHERE      "formulaires"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 112]]
  Question Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE   "questions"."formulaire_id" = ?  [["formulaire_id", 112]]
  Answer Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "answers".* FROM "answers" WHERE  "answers"."question_id" = ?  [["question_id", 153]]
   Answer Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "answers".* FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = ?  [["question_id", 154]]
  Rendered formulaires/show.html.erb within layouts/application (3.3ms)
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (3.0ms)
 Rendered shared/_message.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Completed 200 OK in 82ms (Views: 79.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

When I create a new Form

```
  Started GET "/formulaires/new" for 88.172.93.170 at 2017-12-18 09:30:28  +0000
   Cannot render console from 88.172.93.170! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1,    ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
  Processing by FormulairesController#new as HTML
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  Rendered formulaires/_form.html.erb (29.2ms)
  Rendered formulaires/new.html.erb within layouts/application (30.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered shared/_message.html.erb (0.1ms)
 Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 82ms (Views: 75.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

ANd when I submit my questions and answers :

```
Started POST "/formulaires" for 88.172.93.170 at 2017-12-18 09:33:30 +0000
 Cannot render console from 88.172.93.170! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1,  ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
 Processing by FormulairesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"YAmDvlvqExWqEKyFUXk+9fEOtFyKw/KJL8fbjfDqOox3w0JqjWRYhf  bd4oWSwJXxfVEzuEFsIWOr+vJrF+GoSQ==", "formulaire"=>{"name"=>"aaaaaa", "description"=>"aaaa", "questions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"nom"=>"aaa",  "typequestion"=>"reponse_courte", "_destroy"=>"0"}, "1"=>{"nom"=>"aaa", "typequestion"=>"reponse_courte", "_destroy"=>"0"}}, "answers"=>{"content"=>"aaaa"}}, "commit"=>"Valider le formulaire"}
   User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
 Unpermitted parameter: _destroy
 Unpermitted parameter: _destroy
 Unpermitted parameter: answers
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "formulaires" ("name", "description", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "aaaaaa"], ["description", "aaaa"], ["user_id", 3], ["created_at", "2017-12-18 09:33:30.509450"], ["updated_at", "2017-12-18 09:33:30.509450"]]
   SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "questions" ("nom", "typequestion", "formulaire_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["nom", "aaa"], ["typequestion", 0], ["formulaire_id", 114], ["created_at", "2017-12-18 09:33:30.511078"], ["updated_at", "2017-12-18 09:33:30.511078"]]
  SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "questions" ("nom", "typequestion", "formulaire_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["nom", "aaa"], ["typequestion", 0], ["formulaire_id", 114], ["created_at", "2017-12-18 09:33:30.512317"], ["updated_at", "2017-12-18 09:33:30.512317"]]
   (9.0ms)  commit transaction
   Redirected to https://projetx-hakimghanem.c9users.io/formulaires/114
  Completed 302 Found in 24ms (ActiveRecord: 10.0ms)


  Started GET "/formulaires/114" for 88.172.93.170 at 2017-12-18 09:33:31 +0000
   Cannot render console from 88.172.93.170! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1,   ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
  Processing by FormulairesController#show as HTML
   Parameters: {"id"=>"114"}
   Formulaire Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "formulaires".* FROM "formulaires" WHERE "formulaires"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 114]]
   Question Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE    "questions"."formulaire_id" = ?  [["formulaire_id", 114]]
  Answer Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "answers".* FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = ?  [["question_id", 156]]
  Answer Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "answers".* FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = ?  [["question_id", 157]]
  Rendered formulaires/show.html.erb within layouts/application (2.0ms)
 User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?   ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]] 
 Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (2.2ms)
  Rendered shared/_message.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
 Completed 200 OK in 54ms (Views: 52.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```